# How to define specificity as a callable scorer for model evaluation

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using this code to compare performance of a number of models:

```
from sklearn import model_selection

X = input data
Y = binary labels

models = []
models.append(('LR', LogisticRegression()))
models.append(('LDA', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()))
models.append(('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()))
models.append(('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier()))

results = []
names = []
scoring = 'accuracy'

for name, model in models:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=7)
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X, Y, cv=kfold,scoring=scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %.2f (%.2f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)
```

I can use 'accuracy' and 'recall' as scoring and these will give accuracy and sensitivity. How can I create a scorer that gives me 'specificity'

Specificity= TN/(TN+FP)

where TN, and FP are true negative and false positive values in the confusion matrix

I have tried this

```
def tp(y_true, y_pred): 
error= confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)[0,0]/(confusion_matrix(y_true,y_pred)[0,0] + confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)[0,1])
return error

my_scorer = make_scorer(tp, greater_is_better=True)
```

and then

```
cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X,Y,cv=kfold,scoring=my_scorer)
```

but it will not work for n_split >=10
I get this error for calculation of my_scorer

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1

Comment: Where did `model_selection` suddenly come from?

Comment: What are TN and FP?

Comment: No. 'accuracy' will give accuracy and not precision. You need to use 'precision' for precision. Please see here for all available scoring methods: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html.

Answer (score 20):

If you change the `recall_score` parameters for a binary classifier to `pos_label=0` you get specificity (default is sensitivity, `pos_label=1`)

```
scoring = {
    'accuracy': make_scorer(accuracy_score),
    'sensitivity': make_scorer(recall_score),
    'specificity': make_scorer(recall_score,pos_label=0)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot get specificity in scikit but what you can actually get is `fpr` which is:

```
fpr = 1 - specificity
```

So for getting specificity, you just need to subtract `fpr` from 1.

fpr can be calculated using [`roc_curve`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#receiver-operating-characteristic-roc).

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
y_true = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2])
y_pred = np.array([0.1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.8])
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_true, y_pred)

print(fpr)
# array([ 0. ,  0.5,  0.5,  1. ])

specificity = 1 - fpr
# array([ 1. ,  0.5,  0.5,  0. ])
```

But for the above to work you need to calculate the y_pred by training the model.

If you want to use this inside the cross_val_score, you can make a custom scorer like this:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
def specificity(y_true, y_pred):
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_true, y_pred)
    speci = 1 - fpr
    return speci

from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
scorer = make_scorer(specificity)
```

And then:

```
cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X, Y, cv=kfold,scoring=scorer)
```

NOTE: The above codes will only give correct results for binary `y`.

Comment: Thank you @Vivek Kumar . There should be a way to calculate Specificity. How about this:                
    def tp(y_true, y_pred): 
    error= confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)[0,0]/(confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)[0,0] + confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)[0,1])
    return error

my_scorer = make_scorer(tp, greater_is_better=True)

Comment: @JJoe Hi, I had given this answer to actually calculate specificity, but by mistake written sensitivity. I have corrected the answer now.

Comment: I see your point. But it did not work. I get this error:                                       ValueError: scoring must return a number, got [ 1.  0.] (<class 'numpy.ndarray'>) instead . That said, I defined Specificity using confusion_matrix and it worked!