# sklearn metrics for sensitivity / specificity?

Tags: scikit-learn

I've a Tensorflow model using

```
metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.SensitivityAtSpecificity(xx)]
```

I'm trying to implement a sklearn model with scoring equal to sensitivity or specificity, but if I set

```
scoring='sensitivity'
```

sklearn complains and if I check `sorted(sklearn.metrics.SCORERS.keys())` I see that there isn't any sensitivity or specificity.
So how do I train a model with these 2 metrics?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define specificity as a callable scorer for model evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47704133/how-to-define-specificity-as-a-callable-scorer-for-model-evaluation)